# Privacy Policy Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm developing a Windows Phone 8 app, which access the contacts and photos but does not send the contact nor photos via web, just access the contacts and allow the users to view his contacts in my app.
Do I need to provide Privacy Policy in my app? is that required for Windows App Store?

thanks

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207071(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_BestPractices there's a mention of the privacy policy in the docs. I'd advice to include it. I made once an App using GPS with no online usage, forgot to include the privacy policy (or rather not known that I need one) and it failed certification for that reason.

Comment: Same goes for Windows 8 Store (desktop). I created an app which accesses Internet to get data. It failed on first submission because I had not included link to privacy policy in Settings Charm.